# How to rearrange children of canvas on ArrangeOverride wpf

Tags: wpf, canvas, scale, panel, arrangeoverride

I have canvas, where children are add dynamically to the canvas, lets say an image is placed at left = 50, top 50 when canvas width (500) and height(200). When the window is maximized the canvas width and height changes ( 1000, 400), this time want to rearrange the image position as per canvas width and height. Based on research found that, have to implement

> MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods of panel.

Here user may add any number of items to the canvass, want to scale the children relative to the canvas size.

How to implement the logic in above methods?

Comment: "have to implement MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride". That would be true for a derived Panel, but not for a Canvas. Just recalculate and set Left and Top of the child elements. Or use some other, more appropriate layout panel, like a Grid or DockPanel.

Comment: am using a custom canvas derived from Canvas.

Comment: for downvote , please add comment

Answer (score 1):

You could your implementing your logic (whatever that is) in an event handler for the `SizeChanged` event:

```
private void Canvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = sender as Canvas;
    Size size = e.NewSize;
    foreach (UIElement child in canvas.Children)
    {
        //set the new postion of each element according to your logic
        Canvas.SetLeft(child, );
    }
}
```

---

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="500" Height="200" Background="Yellow" SizeChanged="Canvas_SizeChanged">
    <Button Content="..." Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" />
</Canvas>
```

There is no reason to create a custom `Panel` and override the `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` methods.

Comment: how to calculate the new left and top , based on new canvas size? all the controls are added dynamically.

Comment: How should I know? it is *your* logic.

Comment: its not my logic, based on the question, when the canvas size is increased, how to find the new left based on new canvas width? A control is placed at left 50, when canvas width is (500), when canvas width increases want to set the left as per new width (left value should increase)

Comment: "As per new width..."? What's your forumula for calculating the new left value?

Comment: you didn't got my question correct? if a control is placed in center of the canvas, the control should be in center, even when we view in bigger size window

Comment: Since when is 50 the center of 500...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152560/discussion-between-gani-and-mm8).